# Additional screen time allowance request: when does it time out?

Tags: iphone, parental-controls, screen-time

I am setting up screen time / parental controls for my family.

Now a user asked me for additional minutes via screen time. 15mins for camera, 15mins for photos.

I granted this allowance.

The user didn't use the apps, but after 15 minutes, both apps were again disallowed. So is this additional time really counted from the moment you grant it? I would have expected that this is simply added the user's daily allowance / budget and can be used any time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: when your kid requests additional screen time for the app xy, and you grant it, the additional time starts at the moment you allow it. So it's not *extending* the user's screen time at his/her discretion.

Example:

Your kid has used up all his/her screen time for the day, but asks for 15 more minutes of camera and youtube. You grant it (via Screentime) at 15:00. At 15:15 *both* apps will time out again.

Comment: Is this an answer to your original question, or commentary?  Can you expand further because it's not clear (i.e. *how* do you allow it?).  Also, your question asks *when it times out* and this is describing *when the time starts.*. It's not clear which direction you're going here.